# Upload file to HTML input type='file' that does not belong to a form

Tags: html, forms, curl, post, browser

I am attempting to upload a file via curl that basically should imitate how a user would upload a file to https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/

I can see there is a:

```
<input type="file" id="open-file-dialog" style="display:none" multiple="false" accept=".onnx, .pb, .meta, .tflite, .lite, .tfl, .bin, .keras, .h5, .hd5, .hdf5, .json, .model, .mar, .params, .param, .armnn, .mnn, .ncnn, .dnn, .cmf, .mlmodel, .caffemodel, .pbtxt, .prototxt, .pkl, .pt, .pth, .t7, .joblib, .cfg, .xml">
```

But the input does not belong to any forms - which I haven't seen before. When I try doing a traditional post like:

```
curl -X POST -F ‘data=@example.h5’ https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/
```

It is not permitted. How should I approach uploading a file to that input programmatically? I am trying to automate the creation of these Netron figures, as having to  manually select e.g. 100 files to get 100 figures would be very cumbersome

Thanks!

Comment: what file would you select from the user's computer without their knowledge and why? A file input element does not need to be part of a form if one uses Javascript to handle the upload.

Comment: You want to automatically select file in HTML input? You defensively can't do it via curl unless someone processes that request. I think it's not possible to do what you want

Comment: curl runs on the server whereas javascript runs on the client(browser) - for curl to send the file it needs to be sent that file. Imagine the utter chaos if a website could randomly select files from your computer and send them off into the interwebs without your knowledge

Comment: I am speaking in terms of trying to automate the creation of figures through Netron - Basically it prompts you with a file dialog - but I would like to automate this process. Is there some way to upload a file programmatically to the server without me having to manually select a file in a dropdown?

Comment: For example, Selenium could do it - but that seems... cumbersome to say the least and I was hoping there would be a simpler solution. Do you reckon one exists?

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your comment and others', the HTML issue is probably 1. not feasible; 2. not going to completely solve your goal of automating the creation of figures anyway (fill in the input is only the first step, you still need to automate the export process right?)

Therefore I suggest that the easiest solution is to run your **own instance** of Netron viewer. [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) is an open-source project, and there are many ways to run it on your own computer as given in [its documentation](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron/blob/master/README.md).

The approach you are looking at is to utilise the browser version hosted on `github.io`. The documentation gives all sorts of other ways to run the viewer, macOS/Linux/Windows/Python Server pick one that's most suitable for your situation (depending on your OS and experience in programming) and then write a wrapper script (or hack the initialisation process since you have the source code) to feed the viewer with files and collect outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am aware that I can run my own server - however, that does not solve the problem of automatic figure creation - I would just end up with a local server I have to figure out how to automate the interface of instead. Additionally, because of the way I am collecting the figures, running my own server isn't feasible - and the Netron developers specifically recommend the webapp for that situation (see https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron/issues/162 and https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron/issues/400)